# Best method using regex for this script?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I want to assign categories based upon the format of the book that will be inserted. Let's say there are 3 different formats. comic, hardback, paperback. I'm pulling the data from another website and the current code I have for this particular area is listed below.

```
$string = $item2['data'];   
$number = preg_match("/((Comic)|(Hardcover)|(Paperback))[^A-Za-z]+/", $string, $fields);
$format = $fields[1];
```

The output is either comic, hardcover or paperback

the three parent categories are Comic(1), Hardcover(2), Paperback(3)
Child Categories: Manufacturer(4), Series(5)

The (#)'s being the category ID's for each.

My idea is something like.

```
$number = preg_match("/((Comic))[^A-Za-z]+/", $string, $fields);

if <what goes here for true?> //check to see if value is a comic
    {$cat = array(1,4,5);}
    else
        if <what goes here for true?> //check to see if value is a hardback
            {$cat = array(2,4,5);}
            else                     // if not hardback or comic it must be a paperback
               $cat = array(3,4,5);
```

But.....how would you set it up? Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookup array:

```
$lookup = array(
    'Comic'     => 1,
    'Hardcover' => 2,
    'Paperback' => 3
); 
if (preg_match("/(Comic|Hardcover|Paperback)[^A-Za-z]+/", $string, $match)) {
    $cat = array($lookup[$match[1]], 4, 5);
}
```

With this you can even build the pattern from the array keys:

```
$pattern = '/(' . implode('|', array_map(function($key) { return preg_quote($key, '/'); }, array_keys($lookup))) . ')[^A-Za-z]+/';
```

Comment: Works beautifully thank you! The only thing left in this script that I've spent days on and can't figure out, is how to place data in the weight area on this website. You set the weight with a numerical value and then there' a drop down for pounds, ounces, etc. the plugin is WP Ecommerce. You got any idea how to access that custom meta?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
  preg_match("/(Comic|Hardback|Paperback)[^A-Za-z]+/", $string, $fields);

  switch ($fields[1])
  {

    case ('Comic'):
      $cat = array(1, 4, 5);
      break;

    case ('Hardback'):
      $cat = array(2, 4, 5);
      break;

    case ('Paperback'):
      $cat = array(3, 4, 5);
      break;

    default:
      // Do something if none of above

  }
```

Although what is the expected structure of `$string`? At the moment it will match on anything that contains the word "Hardback" (or "Comic" or "Paperback") and then any characters that aren't letters one or more times. Is this what you want?

Note also that I've explicitly checked for Paperback and included a default. Would make it easier to add other types in the future or if the given data is none of the above (can you be certain that it will only ever be one of these three?)

Edited to incorporate **Basti**'s suggestion (using `$fields` rather than three separate `preg_match`es).